# 'Disabling' the MaxLength Property of a TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a Windows Forms application and I need to have a TextBox which doesn't limit input size to `Int32.MaxValue`.

The problem is that `MaxLength` is an `Int32` Property on the `TextBox` and I of course can't set a number which is greater than that as its value.

Ideally, I don't want to set any number at all and completely 'disable' this check.

Is there any way I can have a `TextBox` which doesn't limit the input size?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set it to zero

> Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows 2000
>   Server, Windows 2000 Advanced Server, Windows XP Home Edition, Windows
>   XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003 Platform Note: If the
>   MaxLength property is set to 0, the maximum number of characters the
>   user can enter is 2147483646 or an amount based on available memory,
>   whichever is smaller.
>
> Windows Millennium Edition Platform Note: If the MaxLength property is
>   set to 0, the maximum number of characters the user can enter is
>   32,766 or an amount based on available memory, whichever is smaller.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx

---

EDIT for windows forms

Comment: +1 This worked...although, something strange is happening when I'm trying to paste a huge string twice in the `TextBox`.  For some reason, when I do the second paste, the text that's displayed in the `TextBox` disappears and it won't let you enter any more characters until you press CTRL+A and hit delete.  But the actual value in the `TextBox` still remains, but just not visible.  

Did anyone ever encounter this?

Comment: @Andreas: How "huge" is this string?

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactor: Note that the limit of 2147483646 is one less than `int.MaxValue` anyway, so it's not like this is giving a bigger limit really.

Comment: As an example, each 'paste' contained a string which is `34464` characters long and I pasted twice.

Comment: @AndreasGrech: You're aware that 34464 is much, much less than `int.MaxValue`, right?

Comment: I am, but that was just an example to repro that issue I hit where the text was disappearing after the second paste.

Comment: @AndreasGrech: My point is that you've got issues much earlier than the limit you can set for `TextBox.MaxLength`, so for the moment you should ignore that. (It's not clear to me why you've accepted this answer, given that the quoted docs show that this *isn't* giving you an unlimited text box any more than setting the max length to `int.MaxValue`...)

Comment: Weird, the information on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength?view=netframework-4.6.1&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.MaxLength);k(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox);k(VS.Properties);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.6.1)%26rd%3Dtrue  doesn't say anything about entering 0 to disable the "maximum length".  I wonder if this still holds true?

Answer (score 5):

The limit of `int.MaxValue` is an unreachable limit anyway. You won't be able to create a string nearly that long. In other words, if you *really* need more than 2<sup>31</sup> characters, you have bigger problems than `TextBox.MaxLength`.

Can I ask when you think it would actually be a usable experience to have more than a 2GB ASCII text file in a single GUI control? If you're looking to write a full text editor which can handle huge files, you probably don't want to be using `TextBox` to start with...

EDIT: I'd actually argue that you probably want to set a limit *smaller* than `int.MaxValue`, determined through testing - at it's likely that other bits of your system will fail before you get close to that limit. Work out what the real limit is, if you like, but I guarantee it'll be lower than `int.MaxValue`...

Comment: But I'm currently writing this application to help with testing, and thus I need to be able to input strings which cross the boundaries to see what happens.

Comment: @AndreasGrech: Cross the boundaries of what? Sanity? Realistically, do you think a limit of (say) 1 billion is going to be a problem for you? Even that may well be too much for a .NET `string`.

Comment: But what if such a "big" string can take the product down?

Comment: A string that big cannot do anything, as it can't exist in the first place.

Comment: @AndreasGrech: It could - but that will happen *before* you get anywhere near the limit you're worrying about.

Comment: Sure, but it can be inputted with malicious intentions.  The thing is, the product that I am testing is not a Windows Forms application, but a web service and I'm sending this big string using a POST request.  The Windows Forms application that I'm talking about is just a helper for testing the web service.

Comment: @AndreasGrech: To test *huge* requests, you'll almost certainly need to write custom code - but by the time you've got a content length that huge, you may find it tricky to test anyway. Fundamentally, you're just not going to be able to reach the limit of `TextBox.MaxLength=int.MaxValue` - so you shouldn't worry about that particular limit.