# Paste DataGridViewTextBoxColumn text beyond 32767

Tags: c#, datagridview

In a C# WinForm, DataGridViewTextBoxColumn cell I need to paste set of characters exceeding 32767. It always truncated at 32767.

Thought of implementing [CellValueChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) event and bind to the relevant cell I need. Is there any other way of implementing this?

Comment: DataGridViewTextBoxColumn has property MaxLinputLength which is an integer.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. Since it's an integer, I set a value larger than 32767 in the properties dialog. Still when I past the test it is limited to 32767. That's the issue I've.

Comment: CellValueChange event handler also identified up to 32767 characters only. private void dgvAttribLits_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

Comment: Why are you doing it in the change event?  Set the property when the grid is initialized.

Comment: Max length set at initialization. During runtime user to paste some text larger than 32767.

Comment: Why don't you just increase the max?  It is just a max.  I do not think it uses more resources if you increase.  Just is a limit.

Comment: Yes I did. Set the properties MaxInputLength to 40000 and still trimmed at 32767, when paste the content in the cell. But I can type after that.

Comment: Then something else is also limiting the length.

Comment: Is the content cut off or only the display?

Comment: @TaW yes, cut off on UI only. If I past (not type) a string larger than default (32767) I can't see anything on UI. But from the backend, correct string is there. That's the content I've pasted.

Comment: The are some limits on the UI; [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709069/the-maximum-number-of-characters-a-textbox-can-display/25709337?r=SearchResults&s=1|41.4957#25709337) is that control surfaces can't display more thar 32k pixels in any direction. Yu may have hit one such limit..

Comment: I changed the DefaultCellStyle, and it works now. Seems the issue is when wrapping the content. DataGridViewCellStyle { WrapMode=True }